# Jquery to toggle elements shows all children

Tags: jquery

I have an html file that is generated from a database. I would like each ul/li section to be independently shown / hidden on click. Example of html.

```
<li class="goal-list">Demo - Learning Spanish guitar</li>
    <ul>
        <li class="task-list">Demo - Playing techniques</li>
            <ul>
                <li class="resource-list 
                "><a href="https://youtu.be/7iVFncQADvc" 
                target=_blank
                onclick="root_path"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>  Demo - Listen to John Williams play and explain</a></li>
                <li class="resource-list 
                "><a href="http://www.thisisclassicalguitar.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Tarrega-Recuerdos.pdf" 
                target=_blank
                onclick="root_path"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>  Demo - Download sheet music</a></li>
                <li class="resource-list 
                "><a href="#" 
                target=_self
                onclick="root_path"><i class="fa fa-music"></i>  Demo - Record own playing</a></li>
                <li class="resource-list 
                "><a href="#" 
                target=_self
                onclick="root_path"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>  Demo - Perform with tutorclass</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li class="task-list">Learn the fretboard </li>
            <ul>
            </ul>
     </ul>
</li>
```

The code below shows / hides every sub-item.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("li.goal-list").click(function(){
        $("li.task-list").toggle(1000);
        return false;
    });

    $("li.task-list").click(function(){
        $("li.resource-list").toggle(1000);
        return false;
    });

});
```

I believe I need to be more specific in finding the tags. I have tried

```
$(this).next("li.resource-list").toggle(1000);

$(this).children("li.resource-list").toggle(1000);

$(this).siblings("li.resource-list").toggle(1000);
```

However, all of these stop the toggle happening at all. Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `$(this).siblings('ul')` to toggle the whole block.
See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/175m2oo6/).

Answer (score 0):

`.children()` doesn't return sub-children, i.e. children of children.
You need to use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

`$(this).find(".resource-list").toggle(1000)` should work.